# Wait until fine-uploader submits all files before submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, fine-uploader

uploader's community!
I am trying to integrate fine-uploader with shrine(ROR).
I am already able to upload images to the server endpoint.
In order to store uploaded photos definitively i opted for sending uploaded photo information(received form the server) with my existing form via ajax.

My existing form looks like this

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="some_path">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" />
    Add some photos
    <div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>
</form>
```

My fine uploader configuration:

```
$(function() {

var fineuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
  template: 'qq-template-gallery',
  debug: true,
  request: {
    endpoint: 'images/cache/upload',
    inputName: "file"

  },
  thumbnails: {
    placeholders: {
      waitingPath: "fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png",
      notAvailablePath: "fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png"

    }

  },
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']

  }

  callbacks: {
    onComplete: maybe add the responseJSON to a local variable and send it later with the form via ajax.
    }
}


});

});
```

My question is: 
How to intercept the sumbit button, so that if fine-uploader is uploading some files :
The form won't be sent, it waits until all uploads are finished and then send it along with the information recieved from the server for each uploaded file(responseJSON).
Hope my question is clear!

Comment: Why do you have fine uploader rendering inside of your form element? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: i don't know? is there a specific reason? i wouldn't mind changing my code.

Comment: I certainly don't know the reason. This is your code, isn't it?

Comment: it is my code! but you said that having fine-uploader rendered inside the form tag dosn't seem to be correct, so i just want to know why so that i change it!

Comment: I guess maybe my question is not clear, in fact i just want to be sure that the files are uploaded before the user quits the page or send the form, i am not sure if fine-uploader has a mecanism to do that, Thanks for your quick reply , i appreciate it

Comment: Fine Uploader already will prevent the page from being reloaded or changed while uploads are in progress. See my answer below for one approach to preventing form submits while uploads are in progress.

Comment: Does Fine Uploader provides any message for the user when it prevents the page from being reloaded or changed? If so how can i customise that message?

Comment: One last thing, can you please tell me why does it seem incorrect to render Fine Uploader in my form, thanks

Comment: "Does Fine Uploader provides any message for the user when it prevents the page from being reloaded or changed?" Yes - you may only change the text, not the styles. This is a browser restriction. See http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#messages.onLeave.

Comment: "why does it seem incorrect to render Fine Uploader in my form?" Because it's not a form field.

Comment: Clear ! One last thing: is there a way to listen to Fine Uploader events? I want to be able to send the form if the user click on the submit button as soon as Fine Uploader finishes uploading all files(i don't care if some uploads failed) i don't want the user to be forced to click on the submit button more than one time.

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the form from being submitted simply by listening for form submit events and preventing the default browser action if files are not yet uploaded.

```
document.getElementById('myForm')
   .addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      var totalFiles = fineuploader.getUploads().length;
      var successfulUploads = fineuploader.getUploads({ 
         status: qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL 
      }).length;

      if (totalFiles !== successfulUploads) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
   })
```

...feel free to add any messaging required to alert your users to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this way (see comments in code for details):

```
var uploadcomplete = 0;

// function called by submit button
function go() {
    // start uploading files
    manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    // check once per second if uploading has completed
    cksub = setTimeout(function() {checksubmit()},1000);
}

function checksubmit() {
    if (typeof(cksub) != 'undefined') clearTimeout(cksub)
    if (uploadcomplete == 0)
        cksub = setTimeout(function() {checksubmit()},1000)
    else 
        document.forms['qq-form'].submit() // submit form
}
```

Then in FineUploader object I defined this callback function:

```
var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
    callbacks: {
         onAllComplete: function() { uploadcomplete=1 } // updates global variable
    },        
    autoUpload: false
})
```

Finally in HTML:

```
<form name="qq-form">
    <div id="fine-uploader-manual-trigger"></div>
    <input type=button onClick='go()'>
<form>
```

Hope it helps!